# How to add a link to the Android or iOS app store in an SMS depending on OS?

Tags: android, ios

I have a mobile application in iOS and Android formats. I run a server containing a database of user telephone numbers, for the purposes of sending an SMS message via Twilio. However, I don't know what operating system each number is associated with. The app does not make HTTP contact with the server.

I want to send a link to each of my users by SMS, which will redirect to the appropriate app store depending on their operating system. Facebook does this - does anyone know how they do it? Do they detect the operating system via the phone number?

Basically, once user click on that link it should automatically redirects to appropriate app store.

Comment: Are you wanting to send an SMS via a user's phone, or from an SMS gateway via a server your app connects to? Why does an app need to detect the phone model?

Comment: sms via server. I just need to send link from my server to user's phone. Each app has different link to their app/play store, that's why I need to detect phone before generating link.

Comment: If you have a remote server, then I imagine you need to connect to an SMS gateway or API, which charge either per message or per bundle of messages. They will often use a REST interface so you can connect to them whatever server-side language you are using. Would you do a web search for this?

Comment: I don't have any problem with sms sending. For that I am using Twilio API and it works fine. The problem is with appstore link. which link should I send for app?

Comment: Each app? Do you mean iOS and Android? I presume these will be completely different builds, so you can wire an app identifier in each one. When you connect to your server to send an SMS, you can send the Android/iOS identifier.

Comment: As soon as I know, What facebook does, is to send direct link to user's mobile. I have no idea how do they detect which phone user's is using?

Comment: Can we detect it from a simple link?

Comment: I think I've explained that, I don't know how to say it another way. Aren't your two operating system builds completely different?

Comment: yeah. Two OS are totally different.

Comment: Right. So, when you connect to your app's server via HTTP, you can declare what operating system the user is using, correct? The Android app declares itself as "android" and the other one as "ios" etc.

Comment: So, first of all I need to send my server's link to user's sms and from that link I need to identify whether it's coming from ios or android. That's what you want to say? But how we'll post OS identifier from that link. Because link will be in SMS. I don't find any way to send that identifier with the link.

Comment: Actually they don't "detect which phone we are using by just phone number". There is no such thing. Its just Android app knows its Android and iOS app knows its an iOS app so app knows for which market it should use url Google Play Market OR Apple Appstore.

Comment: I am confused as to what you do not understand, so let me ensure you have the correct architecture. You have two mobile operating system apps, and they both connect via HTTP to a VPS/cloud server. From that server you connect to Twilio to send SMS messages, again via HTTP. The first leg of HTTP (mobile application to server) can have a URL entirely of your own design, you can put any data in it. So, put the build identifier in this URL.

Comment: @Stan: What links should I use for both? can you provide example link?

Comment: There is no universal link for both. Links are totally different for those two systems.

Comment: @halfer : It's not that. Both applications are on app store and play store. There is nothing to do with my server. I am sending SMS from my server to user's phone.

Comment: @Stan: In that case, how do we know that which link we should use for a user. Because we are not collecting the data regarding their OS. We only have their phone number. that's it.

Comment: App could actually send to your API/server a proper url to market you should include in SMS. So it would be up to application which url to send.

Comment: You are not making yourself very clear, Ronak. Do your apps not at any point contact your server via HTTP? How do you acquire a user's telephone number?

Comment: Ronak, I've edited the question to add in the information that emerged from the comments. If you can add in that level of detail in questions, especially for questions that do not feature code, that is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer: sorry for all misconception. And thanks for edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah. You have users DB represented by the phone number only, right? So you don't actually know which smartphone user has Android or iOS. In this case you should use a special universal url (sent in SMS, most probably shortened) linked to a special webpage on your server with special js (JavaScript, web devs should help on this) intergated. This script should detect which type of device user is using while viewing a webpage and simply redirect to the corresponding market. Also you could provide just both app market links on your page so it will be up to user to choose - in this case no js needed, it could be a very simple html page.

Comment: Yes. here you go. I just wanted to know this thing. Can you please elaborate "help of js" part. How can we detect this thing?

Comment: js is JavaScript. I'm sorry, since I'm an android dev I can't help you on this. Its for web devs.